# Is it possible to use a story's title as a pager in views slideshow?

Tags: drupal-6, view, slideshow

I'm not by any stretch of the imagination a Drupal expert, but I would like to create a views slideshow in Drupal 6, that has the pagers listed vertically on the left of the slideshow (like one of those tabbed content sliders) and uses the stories' titles as pagers instead of the default numerical pagers. Actually, a similar effect can apparently be achieved using the dynamic display block module, but I find it a little iffy and a little buggy so I'm reluctant to use it.

Is it possible to customize views slideshow to that extent?

Any insight into achieving this would be greatly appreciated! 
Many thanks - Jane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach that Miche describes in her very good video here:
She uses it to display the first letter, but you can adapt it to display titles instead:

http://developedbymiche.com/blog/2010/04/18/drupalcon-sf-2010-views-examples-arguments-relationships

(PS: Its also a GREAT video about Views)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Actually I think I'm going to use Views Showcase. It seems to get the job done but it's a whole lot easier to configure than DDBlock. I'm just not sure how much flexibility it offers... but anyway, thanks, your response was much appreciated! :)